# What is the difference between statistical learning and predictive analytics?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, data

I am new to data science. I am confused about the differences between statistical learning and predictive analytics. To me, it looks like both are the same as we try to work on function of x(attributes) for a target value y with very low error. Is this a correct assessment?

Answer (score 0):

Both words can be used interchangeably. However in the interest of a more accurate answer to help you out, you can say statistical methods include the application of mathematical models and fits which aid in the best estimation of the trend for a set of variables in a dataset. These include Regression, Clustering etc.

Predictive analytics deals with the "forecast" aspect of statistical methods. An easy example would be that of regression as you mentioned in your question, deals with a function where x is evaluated to find y.

To conclude we can say that predictive analytics is a subset of statistical methods.